Convergence of generating function on the real line
Suppose I have a sequence of random variable $X_N$ such that for all $s \in \mathbb{R}$
$$ \mathbb{E} e^{s X_N} = e^{a s + \frac{1}{2} b s^2 + E(s,N)}$$
where $|E(s,N)| \leq \frac{C}{N} (1+|s|^3)$ is an error term. It seems obvious to me that $X_N$ should converge as $N \to +\infty$ in distribution to a normal random variable with mean $a$ and variance $b$, however I don't know how to prove this. By Markov's inequality $X_N$ should be fairly tight, i.e. one can easily prove a uniform exponential decay bound on the tails of the distribution of $X_N$.
However all the results I've seen on convergence of generating functions concern complex values of $s$ or discrete random variables. I do not know any inversion formula for the Laplace transform on the real line, at least not one that would interact well with the error $E(s,N)$. How can one show convergence to a normal distribution in this case?

Moment generating functions (MGF) uniquely determine the distribution of a random variable. Because you are already given that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |E(s,N)| = 0$, I think you argue directly that by continuity the MGFs of $(X_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ converge to $e^{as + \frac{1}{2}bs^{2}}, \forall s \in \mathbb{R}$, which is indeed the MGF of a normal random variable with mean $a$ and variance $b$.

@minginator I agree with you but I suppose I am looking for something a bit more quantitative. I would ideally like to say something about the distance to a normal distribution in terms of the error $E$.

I looked around a bit, and this seems to be a more general and rigorous version of what I wrote before. I don't really have a good way to interpret the $E$ term as distance to a normal distribution :(

@minginator Thank you
